# Apply qcut to rolling analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply pandas qcut to a rolling window.  I’m not sure how to go about doing this...idea is to take last 20 days, find the values which fall in the upper quartile, find the averages of values in the upper quartile.  And return the average for that one rolled time series.

So if I have

```
s = pd.Series([5,6,10,12,13,13,20,21,22])
s.rolling(2,2).apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,5))
```

This results in

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
dtype: float64
```

How do I get the qcut intervals for each time series ?  Thanks. Note in the example I have a 2 day rolling window.  It’s just to make things simpler

Comment: You mistyped `lambda`, and `qcut` takes more arguments.

Comment: Hi @ami tavori, I changed it now

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The values in each rolled time series that fall in the upper quartile for that day.  So on day 21, I take last 20 days, find the upper quartile and outvalues for day 21, take average of values in upper quartile and hence thjs is average on day 21.   then repeat for next day and so on

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it by selectioning in your `apply` the `x` that correspond to the highest quartile. With a `rolling` of 6 and `q=4`, you can do:

```
print (s.rolling(6,6).apply(lambda x: x[pd.qcut(x, q=4, labels=[1,2,3,4]) == 4].mean()))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    13.0
6    20.0
7    20.5
8    21.5
dtype: float64
```

I use the `labels` parameter to be able to select the higher quartile (here name 4) that will have different value for each rolling so not sure how to do differently.

Comment: This is really beautiful.  Thank you